# Java 7 path in mac osx

Tags: java, macos, installation

Where is Java 7 installed in mac.

http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u7-b10/jdk-7u7-macosx-x64.dmg

```
JDK 7 Update 07.pkg
```

I downloaded the installer from Oracle, and installation was succeeded. But I can't find it in /System/Library

```
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines] $ ls
1.6.0.jdk
```

Comment: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/<java version>/Contents/Home

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It's under `/Library`, not under `/System/Library`.

Comment: @lan Is it possible to save in any custom location instead of saving it in default location???

Comment: Where? `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` is empty on my machine.

Comment: @Pepijn did you install the _JDK_ or just the _JRE_?  The JRE installs in `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin`, not under `/Library/Java`.

Comment: Just found it. Thanks